# How to preserve a data cell's bold/italics in a linked text box

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have this formatted text in cell `A7` of worksheet `myworksheet`:

> My **bold** and *italic* text.

I can get this text to show up in a text box in a chart by setting the formula for the text box to this:

`=myworksheet!A7` (Excel changes it to `=myworksheet!$O$7`)

That will get the text, but it won't keep the **bold** and *italic* formatting.

Is there a way to preserve the bold and italics in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Formulas only reference the *value* of a cell, not the format data.

Unfortunately, there is no way for a formula to reference the formatting of a specific cell, you will have to apply that formatting to the cell, or copy and paste special (all using source theme) instead of referencing.

Comment: Conditional formatting might be applied as a solution, but this answer is correct, you can't link the format

Comment: @datatoo, what do you mean by conditional formatting? Would that be able to apply to part of the cell content (e.g. just a word or two), not the whole cell content?

Comment: that isn't possible. If all you need is a display of the cell, you might try after copying a cell  Shift+Edit+PastePictureLink in the target. It will be an image not the actual content, which may not work for you.